# cutting text from one line and appending it to another with sed

Tags: sed

I am having trouble doing an in-place text substitution with sed that involves multi-line patterns. I specifically need to cut a pattern from one line and append it to the end of the first occurrence of another pattern on a separate line. When the text is appended to the line containing the second pattern, there also needs to be some additional text added on both sides of the pattern being pasted.

In my case, the search range is as follows:
`/^find.* | while/,/^done/`

All text before `| while` needs to be cut, and then pasted it to the end of `^done`.

In doing this, the pasted text should also be surrounded by characters as follows:
 `< <(`PASTED TEXT`)`

Finally, the pipe at the beginning of line cut from should be removed: `/^| while/s/^| //`

For example, if the file contains the following:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n\0" | sort -z | while read -d $'\0' a
do
    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    declare select"${cnt}"="${a}"
    name="${a}"
    echo "Type ${cnt} for ${name::-5}"
done
```

The resulting text should be:

```
while read -d $'\0' a
do
    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    declare select"${cnt}"="${a}"
    name="${a}"
    echo "Type ${cnt} for ${name::-5}"
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n\0" | sort -z)
```

Note that the files being changed have multiple occurrences of these kinds of situations. These substitutions would be ran from a bash script. `sed -i -e '<expression>' "$changeme"`

Is this possible to do this in sed? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how will you handle nested loops (eg. `find ... | while ...; do ...; for ...; do ...; done; ...; done`) ? what about commented-out lines with broken syntax?

Comment: I'll handle nested loops by calling sed again with a separate substitution that ensures spaces are present.

Basically, for those situations, the search range would be:
`/^[[:space:]]\+find.* | while/,/^[[:space:]]\+done/`

Then, the spaces would be preserved through the use of capture groups. e.g. `\(^[[:space:]]\+\)` and `\1`. There are no situations where something is nested at a third level so this method would be safe.

Commented out lines are not a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific case of groups of lines where:

- first line starts with `find` and then contains `| while`
- final line starts with `done`

you could try:

```
sed -i.old '
    /^find.* | while/,/^done/ {

        /^\(find.*\) | \(while.*\)/ {
            # create and store new final line
            h
            s//done < <(\1)/
            x

            # edit start line
            s//\2/
            b
        }

        # load new final line
        /^done/ x
    }

    # print (possibly-edited) line

' file
```

It may be safe to rearrange the code to avoid having to specify the start/finish regex twice:

```
sed -i.old '
    1 {
        h
        s/.*/done/
        x
    }
    /^(find.*\) | (while.*\)/ {
        h
        s//done < <(\1)/
        x
        s//\2/
        b
    }
    /^done$/ x
' file
```

Preload hold space with the default final line.

After a (potential) final line matches, it resets the stored line so `x` becomes a no-op until a new start line has been processed.

So unrelated `done` lines are not affected as long as they are not nested (with inappropriate indentation) inside the `find | while` loop.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to explain that a bit? I'm having some difficulty getting a grasp of holding space and the branching command.

Comment: branch is just another name for goto, either to a labelled statement or the end of the script if no label. hold and pattern space can be thought of as simple variables - you can overwrite one with the other (`h`,`g`) or append one to the other (`H`,`G`), or swap their values (`x`)

Comment: you might find it instructive to work through what this code is doing: `seq 20 | sed '1!G;$b;x;d'`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just match the loop-terminating `done` indent against whatever indent the loop-beginning `find` had so you don't need to call the script multiple times for nested loops?

For example, given this input file with nested loops (and blank lines added just to improve readbility):

```
$ cat file
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n\0" | sort -z | while read -d $'\0' a
do
    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    declare select"${cnt}"="${a}"

    find . -name foo "%P\n\0" | tac | while read -d $'\0' a
    do
        echo 'the sky is falling'

        find . -type f | while read line
        do
            echo 'Oh, wait, no its not'
        done

    done

    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    name="${a}"
    echo "Type ${cnt} for ${name::-5}"

done
```

then, using GNU awk for inplace editing and the 3rd arg to `match()`, this:

```
$ awk -i inplace '
    match($0,/(^find\s.*\S)\s*[|]\s*(while\s.*)/,a) {
        cmd = a[1]
        $0 = a[2]
        inLoop = 1
    }
    inLoop && /^done/ {
        $0 = $0 " < <(" cmd ")"
        inLoop = 0
    }
    { print }
' file
```

will do just the first level of loop as you asked for:

```
$ cat file
while read -d $'\0' a
do
    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    declare select"${cnt}"="${a}"

    find . -name foo "%P\n\0" | tac | while read -d $'\0' a
    do
        echo 'the sky is falling'

        find . -type f | while read line
        do
            echo 'Oh, wait, no its not'
        done

    done

    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    name="${a}"
    echo "Type ${cnt} for ${name::-5}"

done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n\0" | sort -z)
```

but alternatively we can capture the indent before the start of the `find`, and the actual `find ... | sort | ...` command in arrays `idt[]` and `cmd[]` indexed by our current loop level as stored in a variable `lvl`, and then just print them as appropriate when we hit the first `done` at the same indent:

```
$ awk -i inplace '
    match($0,/^(\s*)(find\s.*\S)\s*\|\s*(while\s.*)/,a) {
        idt[++lvl] = a[1]
        cmd[lvl] = a[2]
        $0 = a[1] a[3]
    }
    lvl && ( $0 ~ ("^" idt[lvl] "done") ) {
        $0 = $0 " < <(" cmd[lvl--] ")"
    }
    { print }
' file
```

which when run on the original input file above will output:

```
$ cat file
while read -d $'\0' a
do

    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    declare select"${cnt}"="${a}"

    while read -d $'\0' a
    do
        echo 'the sky is falling'

        while read line
        do
            echo 'Oh, wait, no its not'
        done < <(find . -type f)

    done < <(find . -name foo "%P\n\0" | tac)

    cnt=$(( "${cnt}"+1 ))
    name="${a}"
    echo "Type ${cnt} for ${name::-5}"

done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n\0" | sort -z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt (mostly to learn myself). I didn't think to consider nested loops:

```
sed -i.bak -n -e '
/^find.* \| while /,/^done/ {
        /^find/ {
                h
                s/\(^find.* \| \)\(while.*$\)/\2/
                p
                x
                s/ | while.*$//
                h
        }
        /^find/! {
                /^done/! p
                /^done/ {
                        x
                        s/.*/done < <(\0)/
                        p
                }
        }
}' "$changeme"
```

Comment: For portability, use `&` instead of `\0`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).